# Add Macro to Excel Ribbon in Add-In

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I made an excel macro that retrieves data from other workbooks. I need to add a button to the Excel Ribbon for this Macro. The kicker: I need this button to go into a tab called "Special". This tab was part of an add-in and currently only contains one button. This "Special" Tab cannot be found in the customize ribbon area in the options tab.

Also, would it be better to turn my one macro into an add-in or should I just add the one macro to the ribbon.

Thank you all very much in advanced.

[image]

Comment: *This tab was part of an add-in* - you'll need the add-in to be able to manipulate the ribbon content

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have the add-in file and access to the VBA code, do I need anything else?

Comment: Yes. You;ll need Microsoft Custom UI Editor (free dowload) to manipulate the custom ribbon bar. Technically, you don't need this, but its a lot easier than zipping the xl file and adjusting the xml file there and saving it back.

Comment: In my experience, trying to edit Excel's ribbon tends to lead to frustration. Another option is to use VBA to create a UserForm that can serve as the interface/GUI of your add-in. You then assign a hotkey to show this UserForm (maybe like alt+Q). So a user presses alt+Q and then the UserForm with all your add-in's subroutines pops up. You have way more flexibility with a UserForm than you would have with a ribbon, so it's an interesting option. VBA doesn't excel (no pun intended) at many things, but it's actually quite decent for easily making GUIs.

Comment: why (according to your experience) does it leads to frustration @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero ?